# Como funciona ponteiro para função em PHP?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem

Em C é possível utilizar ponteiros em funções para referenciar outras funções, veja um exemplo:

```
int somar(int a, int b) 
{
    return a + b;
}

int (*sPtr)(int,int);

int main(void) 
{
    sPtr = &somar;
    
    int r = sPtr(10, 5);
    
    printf("Soma: %i", r);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

> Soma: 15

Em PHP consegui referenciar uma função apenas guardando o nome dela em uma variável e a mesma variável passou a apontar para a função. Veja o exemplo:

```
<?php
function somar($a, $b) 
{
    return $a + $b;
}

$s = 'somar';

$r = $s(10, 5);

echo 'Soma: ' . $r;
```

Saída:

> Soma: 15

Esta forma de referenciar funções do PHP me gerou uma dúvida que esta logo a abaixo.

## Dúvida

Existe ponteiro para função em PHP, se existe como ele funciona?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Com PHP a aritmética de ponteiros é meio obscura para os desenvolvedores, justamente por esse motivo é uma linguagem de mais alto nível.

É possível apenas referenciar funções em PHP utilizando 3 métodos:

1. Funções anonimas, ou clojures

Neste modelo podemos referenciar uma variável como obtendo o valor de uma função:

```
$fn = function($a, $b) { return $a+$b; };
```

2. Passando como parâmetro

Assim como passamos números, também podemos executar uma função por um parâmetro

```
function exec($fn) {
  return $fn();
}
```

3. Como string

Por "reflexão" o PHP consegue atribuir o nome de uma função passada via string para um ponteiro de função (que é exatamente o que você fez acima)

```
function soma($a, $b) { 
    return $a+$b; 
}

$e = "soma";
echo $e(10, 5);
```

Fora isso creio que não haja nenhum outro modo. Mas dê uma olhada aqui:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475136/pass-a-function-by-reference-in-php